# counter cache is not working after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

pages model

```
has_many :categorization
has_many :categories, :through => :categorization
```

category model

```
has_many :categorization
has_many :pages, :through => :categorization
```

categorization model

```
belongs_to :page
belongs_to :category, :counter_cache => :pages_count
```

when i edit page and change categories of page, it doesn't update pages_count. Am i missing something or is this normal? How can i make it work?

Update:

i have pages_count column on categories table and counter cache is working after create and destroy.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. This problem was fixed in Rails 3.1.0.beta. Maybe it helps others who has the same problem. It took 4 hours for me to find out.
[Commit is here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/52f09eac5b3d297021ef726e04ec19f6011cb302)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

According to the docs you need to add a column to the page table such as `#{table_name}_count`.

run a new migration:

```
script/generate migration add_category_count_to_pages
```

Then add this do the migration:

```
add_column :pages, :categories_count, :integer
```

Then `rake db:migrate`

And that should take care of it.

## update

The counter cache needs to be placed on the associated table:

categorization.rb model:

```
belongs_to :page, :counter_cache => :pages_count
belongs_to :category
```

Comment: no sir, i have all tables set. Counter cache is working after create or destroy.

Comment: it looks like you need to put it on the associated class, so on post, not categories.